# In tabular hline and matrixs overlap

Tags: tables, matrices, line

I write matrix in table but it is too close to the line. When it be printed, it looks bad.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\mode<presentation>{\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter%matris boyu
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
    \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |}
            \hline
            Örnek1.2a: & Örnek 1.2b: & Örnek1.2c \\
            Tek çözüm & Çözümsüz & Sonsuz çözümlü \\ \hline
            $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            10&6&4\\
            2&4&7\\
            2&5&8
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            12&8&6\\
            2&4&7\\
            0&3&6
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            6&5&7\\
            13&9&7\\
            2&4&7\\
            1&4&7
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
            $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&0\\
            0&0&1\\
            1&0&0\\
            1&0&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&0\\
            1&1&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&1\\
            0&1&1\\
            1&1&1
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline    
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

It is obtained by help of `makecell`packages macros `\setcellgapes{3pt}` and `\makegapedcells`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,bm}
\mode<presentation>{\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
%\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter%matris boyu
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][\arraystretch]{%
    \edef\arraystretch{#1}%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}


    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |}
            \hline
            Örnek1.2a: & Örnek 1.2b: & Örnek1.2c \\
            Tek çözüm & Çözümsüz & Sonsuz çözümlü \\ \hline
            $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            10&6&4\\
            2&4&7\\
            2&5&8
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            12&8&6\\
            2&4&7\\
            0&3&6
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            6&5&7\\
            13&9&7\\
            2&4&7\\
            1&4&7
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
            $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&0\\
            0&0&1\\
            1&0&0\\
            1&0&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&0\\
            1&1&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&1\\
            0&1&1\\
            1&1&1
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its key `cell-space-limits`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,bm}
\mode<presentation>{\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}[cell-space-limits=4pt]
            \hline
            Örnek1.2a: & Örnek 1.2b: & Örnek1.2c \\
            Tek çözüm & Çözümsüz & Sonsuz çözümlü \\ \hline
            $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            10&6&4\\
            2&4&7\\
            2&5&8
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            4&3&5\\
            12&8&6\\
            2&4&7\\
            0&3&6
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            6&5&7\\
            13&9&7\\
            2&4&7\\
            1&4&7
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
            $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&0\\
            0&0&1\\
            1&0&0\\
            1&0&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&1&1\\
            0&0&0\\
            0&0&0\\
            1&1&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&1\\
            0&1&1\\
            1&1&1
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ \hline
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility (as separated answer since original has been already accepted as it is) with `tblr` of (new) `tabularray` package with keys `colsep` and `rowsep`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath, bm}
\mode<presentation>{\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Solution by use of the \texttt{tabularray} package}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, 
             cells={c},
             colsep=4pt, rowsep=3pt
             }
{Örnek1.2a:\\ Tek çözüm}
    & {Örnek 1.2b:\\  Çözümsüz}
        & {Örnek1.2c\\ Sonsuz çözümlü}     \\ 
$D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
    4&3&5\\
    10&6&4\\
    2&4&7\\
    2&5&8
        \end{bmatrix}$ 
    & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
        4&3&5\\
        12&8&6\\
        2&4&7\\
        0&3&6
            \end{bmatrix}$ 
        & $D_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
                6&5&7\\
                13&9&7\\
                2&4&7\\
                1&4&7
                \end{bmatrix}$ \\
$R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&1&0\\
    0&0&1\\
    1&0&0\\
    1&0&0
        \end{bmatrix}$ 
    & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
        0&1&1\\
        0&0&0\\
        0&0&0\\
        1&1&0
            \end{bmatrix}$ 
        & $R_{A,b}=\begin{bmatrix}
            0&0&1\\
            0&0&1\\
            0&1&1\\
            1&1&1
            \end{bmatrix}$ \\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]